# restoring log files using tsql script

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Hi I have log  files in my c drive as databasename_yyyymmddhhmm.trn0 formate . We get 3 transaction log files every 30 minutes which ends with 0,1,2.
I'm using

```
Restore database [databasename]
From disk=N 'c:\foldername\databasename_yyyymmddhhmm.trn0',
Disk = N 'c:\foldername\databasename_yyyymmddhhmm.trn1',
Disk= N 'c:\foldername\databasename_yyyymmddhhmm.trn2'
With norecovery
Go
```

To restore log files . But I want to make it continuous process for every 30 minutes where the file name changes every 30minutes with a timestamp 
For example : databasename _201701260700.trn0
After 30 minutes we get another file like databasename_201701260730.trn0
So how can  I 'change my query' ,so that the i can run every 30minutes in sql server agent job  with change in the time stamp .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't be sure that the log file will have the exact time you are looking for, so I would go get the file itself with something like:

```
DECLARE @fileLocation VARCHAR(128) = 'c:\foldername\'                             
--DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(128)                                                                  

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Get a list of all the file names in the directory
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FileNames') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #FileNames
CREATE TABLE #FileNames (
     id int IDENTITY(1,1)
     ,subdirectory nvarchar(512)
     ,depth int
     ,isfile bit
     ,LogTime datetime null)
INSERT #FileNames (subdirectory,depth,isfile)
EXEC xp_dirtree @fileLocation, 1, 1
```

Then, update that table to parse the file name into the LogTime using `SUBSTRING` or `LEFT` and `RIGHT` to get the yyymmddhhmm for your log file. Here's an example:

```
update #FileNames
set LogTime = left(right('subdirectory',17),12)
```

That's basicaly doing this:

```
select left(right('c:\foldername\databasename_yyyymmddhhmm.trn0',17),12)
```

Then, build your dyamic sql with the file names, based off the last 3 in your table. Booyakasha!

Comment: Thanks a lot scsimon I will try this procedure . Happy weekend

Comment: Cheers @Sql let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Hi @scsimon. I have a question regarding replication . We get a nightly full backup and log backup every 30 minutes starts at 7 in the morning and ends at 2 am. So how can I keep my database update every 30 minutes so that I can replicate the data from one database to another database .

Comment: @SQL I'm not 100% clear on what you are trying to do, but it sounds like you are trying to keep one DB somewhat in sync with another DB, or have 1 DB a day behind another. This type of question is better suited for dba.stackexchange.com and is really outside the scope of your inital question. I would look into [replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) if this is what you are trying to accomplish.